# Circular shorting in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have got a sql server table with following details

> Cleint_ID   Photo_Rank
>  2   1
>   1   9
>  3   7
>   1   6
>  1   5
>   1   7
>  3   8
>   3   5
>  1   4
>   2   3
>  2   2
>   1   9
>  3   7

now i want to arrange all the photos in order that first one one photo of all clients will be displayed of top ranked then .. the n second highest ranked photo of all client and continue

I want result

> Cleint_ID1   highest photo rank rank of 1 if found
>   Cleint_ID2   highest photo rank rank of 2 if found
>   Cleint_ID3   highest photo rank rank of 3 if found
>   Cleint_ID1   second  highest photo rank of 1 if
>   found
>  Cleint_ID2   second highest photo rank of 2
>   if found
>  Cleint_ID3   second  highest photo rank
>   of 3 if found

and continue

![http://www.impressivefm.com/one.png]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the RANK function can be used as below:

```
select Client_id, photo_rank, rank_ordinal
from (select Client_ID, photo_rank,
        RANK() over (PARTITION BY Client_ID ORDER BY Photo_Rank) as rank_ordinal
    from TableName) _
order by rank_ordinal, client_id
```

Comment: giving wrong result... i want to circulate client id with their hiehest ranked photo... so first row will be client 1 -- with height ranked photo... second row --- height of client 2..... next highest of client 3.... then again height of client 1, 2 and so on

Comment: @AlifAli, Eduard Uta had the gist of the answer. Please try the now expanded answer.

Comment: @Shannon Severance, thanks for the update! This looks indeed like the correct answer (also ran a quick test to confirm). I updated it and added a missing comma after photo_rank, in the inline view.

Comment: @Alif Ali, for reversing the ranking (higher ranks first) the "(PARTITION BY Client_ID ORDER BY Photo_Rank DESC)" should help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

You can Use **Max with Partition BY Clause**
Which Gives you max values among partitions partitions

```
select 'Client_ID' +CAST(Client_ID as VARCHAR(10)) as Client_ID ,
MAX(Photo_rank) as MaxRank from 
(
select MAX(Photo_rank) over(partition by Client_ID )as RN ,*
 from Mytable)D
 group by  Client_ID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Client_ID   MaxRank 
Client_ID1  9
Client_ID2  3
Client_ID3  8
```

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help.. i think this is technically not possible.. have to do manual coding... thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

1. CREATE #TEMP WITH DISTINCT CLIENT_ID
2. CREATE #ID_LIST WITH THE 3 HIGHEST Photo_Rank
3. BUILD THE FINAL TABLE WITH CURSOR

```html
--CREATE TABLE #TEMP (Cleint_ID INT)
--CREATE TABLE #ID_LIST (ID int IDENTITY(1,1)  ,Cleint_ID INT,Photo_Rank INT)
INSERT INTO #TEMP (Cleint_ID )
SELECT DISTINCT Cleint_ID
FROM [SCORE]
DECLARE cur cursor FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
 SELECT  Cleint_ID
 FROM #TEMP
DECLARE @d INT
OPEN cur
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @d
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
 BEGIN 
INSERT INTO #ID_LIST (Cleint_ID,Photo_Rank)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3  Cleint_ID,Photo_Rank
 FROM [SCORE]  
WHERE Cleint_ID =@D
ORDER BY Cleint_ID,Photo_Rank DESC
FETCH NEXT FROM cur  INTO @d
END
Close  cur 
DEALLOCATE cur
--TRUNCATE TABLE #TEMP
--TRUNCATE TABLE #ID_LIST
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (Cleint_ID INT,Photo_Rank INT)
DECLARE @ID INT=-2 
DECLARE @X INT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP)
WHILE @X!=0 
BEGIN
WHILE @ID<=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #ID_LIST)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @TBL
SELECT DISTINCT Cleint_ID,Photo_Rank FROM #ID_LIST
WHERE ID=@ID+3
SET @ID=@ID+3
END
SET @X=@X-1
SET @ID=@ID-11
PRINT @ID
END
SELECT * FROM @TBL
```

[image]

Comment: @AlifAli IT IS FOR YOU TO DECIDE IF YOU WANT LINE 16 TO BE DISTINCT OR NOT

Comment: YOU WILL NEED TO 'ADJUST' THIS LINE (SET @ID=@ID-11) ACCORDING TO YOUR TABLE SIZE. CHANGE THE NAME 'SCORE' TO YOUR TABLE NAME